# Set the bounds of a CSS animation

Tags: css, animation

I have apparent gaps in my CSS experience.  While I can easily apply and extend what I do know, I'm missing the terms to even search for what I don't know.

So, I've taken parts of [Animation.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and applied them, but I don't know how to constrain the bounds of animations like `bounceInUp`.  When the animation happens, the transition seems to have no bounds.  I'd like to constrain the bounds of the animation so that it starts and finishes inside its container.

What am I trying to do here?  Constrain the bounds, clip the animation, mask it?  I've been digging and haven't found what I'm looking for yet.
[image]

Comment: Never used Animation.css, but have you tried setting `overflow: hidden` on the `<div>`?

Comment: @Hatchet I tested that; however, it doesn't really define the bounds so that it starts at the edge of the container.  Instead it just hides it while outside the container.  In a bind, I'd settle for that; however, I'm just prototyping now and would like to understand how to get the animation to start at the edge of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to set the starting position in the CSS's translate3d().  Not sure if that is the "right" way, but it has the right effect for me.  I'm not sure what I was expecting to find; however, I don't particularly like this approach because I'll have to tweak the animation CSS based on the size of the container element. I'd prefer to just code the CSS solution once and freely resize containers.

```css
@keyframes bounceInUp {
  from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  from {
    opacity: 0;
    /* Set the y length(?) / offset position */
    transform: translate3d(0, 300px, 0);
  }
}
```